# Convert Find Dupes Query to Delete Dupes Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This works totally fine for me to find dupes in a table in Google Big Query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY KeyReport,Analytics,Description,AsOfDate)
          row_number
  FROM `corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics`
)
WHERE row_number > 1 AND AsOfDate IN('01-03-2019','01-17-2019')
```

I thought I could just change the `Select *` to `Delete` and run it to delete dupes, but it's throwing an error about an incorrect '(' character.  That can't be right.  The error has to be attributable to something else, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your call to `ROW_NUMBER` does make much sense, because you never provided an `ORDER BY` clause.  Without this, you are basically telling BigQuery that you don't really care about what order is used to determine the row number.  That aside, here is a query you may try to delete your records:

```
DELETE
FROM corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics AS c
WHERE
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate
                               ORDER BY some_column)
     FROM corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics AS c2
     WHERE d.id = d2.id) = 1 AND
    AsOfDate IN ('01-03-2019', '01-17-2019');
```

This assumes that there exists some primary key, or other unique key, column `id` which can be used to uniquely identify any record in your table.  If that doesn't exists, then we would have to correlate the subquery in the `WHERE` clause using some other method.

Comment: There is no unique ID in the table.  How do I modify the SQL to account for this?  Also, can't I delete the dupe-records in place?  Somehow this is creating a new table, called 'Updates'.  There must be some kind of setting that controls this because I'm not explicitly telling it to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> it's throwing an error about an incorrect '(' character. That can't be
>   right.

It is exactly right. Parser expects to see table name after FROM, instead it is seeing '(' and throwing an error. See Tim Biegeleisen answer on how to modify your SQL.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax

```
DELETE [FROM] target_name [alias]
WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need an EXISTS in there:

DELETE
FROM corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics AS c
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KeyReport, Analytics, Description, AsOfDate
                               ORDER BY some_column)
     FROM corp-analytics.Reports.Metrics AS c2
     WHERE d.id = d2.id) = 1 AND
    AsOfDate IN ('01-03-2019', '01-17-2019');